# why the php script does not have permission to write

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I write a simple php script to check if the php process has the permission to write into specific folder.

```
<!-- check if apache has write permission in specific folder -->
<?php
$folder = '/var/www/html/easyappointments/storage/';
// $folder = '/tmp/';
$testfile = '.testfile';
// get whoami
$whoami = `whoami`;
//echo whoami and start a new line
echo "the user running the PHP script is : $whoami <BR>";

//check what permissions the folder has
$perms = fileperms($folder);
//convert the permissions to octal
$perms = substr(sprintf('%o', $perms), -4);
echo "The folder $folder has permissions in octal: $perms <BR>";

//tell who is the owner of the folder
$owner = fileowner($folder);
//what is the real name of the owner
$owner = posix_getpwuid(fileowner($folder));
echo "The folder $folder is owned by: $owner[name] <BR>";

if (is_writable($folder)) {
    if ($fp = fopen($folder . $testfile, 'w')) {
        echo "The file $folder$testfile is writable";
        fclose($fp);
        unlink($folder . $testfile);
    } else {
        echo "The file $folder$testfile is not writable";
    }
} else {
    //echo why the folder is not writable
    echo "The folder $folder is not writable because the permissions are: $perms <BR>";
}
```

after running it in chrome browser, the output of above script is

#####################

the user running the PHP script is : apache

The folder /var/www/html/easyappointments/storage/ has permissions in octal: 0777

The folder /var/www/html/easyappointments/storage/ is owned by: apache

The folder /var/www/html/easyappointments/storage/ is not writable because the permissions are: 0777

#####################

I am totally confused about why 'apache'(running the PHP script) can not write into one folder owned by 'apache'.

my environment is as follow:

1. Centos 7
2. PHP 7.3.33
3. Apache 2.4.6

How to ensure my PHP script to be with permission to write into one specific folder. How to grant permissions to the folder?

Comment: Check your ACLs, it may be different from chmod.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I find this weird issue is caused by SELinux. the SELinux blocks the read/write operations although I have set permissions properly using chmod and chown.